# How can I use jquery to append a div for me which also includes all of it's nested divs as well?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a user creates a product, I want that product to be broadcasted to all other users and dynamically added to their screens. So far the broadcast aspect works amazingly.

But how can I dynamically add in this '.product' class, as well as all of a nested divs in an easy way? At the moment the only thing I can think of is copying and pasting all of it's divs in a jquery variable and adding it that way- there must be an easier way.

Here is where products are first loaded in when the page loads

```
<div class="product" id="{{$product->id}}">
                            <div class="product-image"><img src="/imgs/products/{{$product->type_id}}.png"></div>
                            <div class="product-content">
                                <div class="product-title" id="product-title">
                                    {{ strtoupper(\App\ProductType::where('id', $product->type_id)->first()->name)}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-price">PRICE PER UNIT: <div class="price-value" id="price">{{$product->price}}</div> EXENS</div>
                                <br/>
                                QUANTITY: <div class="quantity-value" id="quantity">{{$product->quantity_available}}</div>
                                @if(strpos(\App\Group::where('id', $player->group_id)->first()->options, "\"showName\":true") !== false)
                                    <br/>
                                    SELLER: <div class="seller" id="seller">{{\App\User::where('id',$product->seller_id)->first()->name}}</div>
                                @endif
                                <br/>
                                PRICE: <div class="total-price" id="total-price">{{$product->price * $product->quantity_available}}</div>
                                <form class="buy-product-form"  action="/UoE/buy-product/{{$product->id}}" method="POST">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    <button class="pull-right btn btn-primary">BUY NOW</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                     </div>
```

When the event is received the only way I can think of doing it as:

```
var productToAdd="<div class='buy-product-form'><div id='price'></div> " +
                    "" +
                    "" + //insert a massive string here containing all the other aforementioned sub-divs
                    "" + //And populate with json data
                    "" +
                    "</div>";

                $('.content').append(productToAdd);
```

Comment: you can get dynamically created `divs` in one variable at the time of creation, like `var productToAdd = document.getElementsByClassName('buy-product-form')[0];` and use `$('.content').append(productToAdd);`. This will save you from copy pasting entire product each time.

Comment: Okay, can I still populate the tags with custom JSON data as well? By using the html() tag?

Comment: Yes you can, but make sure that your json does not contain any invalid html characters, json will appear as text when you append it, you should parse json and then append it by creating structure you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to take the entire code posted in the question and do make it as a one big HTML tag. That way my JS function can append the page with a HTML product div and it will already be bound with the necessary event listeners.